# How to use reactotron-redux with easy-peasy?

Tags: react-native, redux, easy-peasy, reactotron

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-cycle */
import {action, createStore} from 'easy-peasy';
import reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import {applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import drawerModal from '../models/drawerModal';


let initialState = {};

const store = createStore(
  {
    drawerModal,
    reset: action(() => ({
      ...initialState,
    })),
  },
  {name: 'easystore', compose: applyMiddleware([reactotron.createEnhancer()])}
);

initialState = store.getState();
export default store;
```

I try this way but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 29 Aug 2022**, its working by following way

config file ReactotronConfig.js

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux'

const reactron= Reactotron.configure({
  name: 'My App',
  host: '192.168.1.9',
})
  .useReactNative({
    storybook: true,
    asyncStorage: false, // there are more options to the async storage.
    networking: {
      // optionally, you can turn it off with false.
      ignoreUrls: /symbolicate/,
    },
    editor: false, // there are more options to editor
    overlay: false, // just turning off overlay
  })
  .use(reactotronRedux()) 
  .connect();

  export default reactron
```

use that file in store.js

```
import {action, createStore} from 'easy-peasy';

import exploredMovies from './models/exploredMovies';
import reactron from '../helpers/ReactotronConfig';

let initialState = {};
window.requestIdleCallback = null;
const store = createStore(
  {

    exploredMovies,
    reset: action(() => ({
      ...initialState,
    })),
  },
  {name: 'easystore', enhancers: [reactron.createEnhancer()]}
);

initialState = store.getState();
export default store;
```

===========================================

**12 July 2022**

[image]

I discussed with the community and its not supported